# How to count the values to prepare make stacked bar chart

Tags: pandas, group-by, count, bar-chart

I'm wondering how to count the values in a column to make a stacked bar chart
For example, the data is like below

[image]

I'd like to make a stacked bar chart with x="Main", which has the "Detail" values counts.
All dtype is object.

What I tried to count the 'Detail' Values is

```
df['count'] = df['Detail'].value_counts()
```

But the count column has the value only NaN everytime.
[image]

Can you share your solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `pd.crosstab` and `plot.bar`:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['Main'], columns=df['Detail']).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Input dataframe given as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Main':[*'AAABBBC'],
                   'Detail':[*'aabbcda']})
```

Or stacked:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['Main'], columns=df['Detail']).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]